# AOP vs Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

What the difference between these below...

```
@org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
public class Test {
   //@Pointcut, @Around etc etc..
}
```

And

```
public aspect Test {

}
```

And what is the better to use for security among..

- Spring Security &
- AOP

in spring app

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check [here](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-aspects.html)

> Aspect declarations are supported by the
>   org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect annotation. The declaration:
>
> ```
>  @Aspect
>  public class Foo {}
> ```
>
> Is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>  public aspect Foo {}
> ```

**NOTE**: The first one is detected by spring. The later requires AspectJ.

And for the second question. The comparison is impossible. Because the first one is a framework and the later is a paradigm. Spring security uses AOP to secure method calls, AOP by itself is not a security mechanism. Unless of course, you are going to build your own security using AOP, which is re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: That means if I want to customize my security part myself then Core AOP is better. And to get ordered code then Spring Security Framework is fine, isn't it ?

Comment: Spring is a full blown security suit... It can support all kinds of use cases, so I recommend u check out the documentation. 
To create a functional security you need much more than AOP, AOP  is barely a way to intercept method calls. Securing requires much more. 
You can create the filters, the providers, the controller... yourself, but why? Spring Security is used to secure all kinds of projects, including financial systems.

Comment: OK of course I will read out the Spring Security Doc.
By the way, what about the Struts ! Can I use AOP in my existing struts1 project ?

Comment: @M.A.Khomeni I'm not familiar with struts, but AOP is kind a Java class thing, So you should be able to apply it there!
And don't forget to mark the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

Marking your class `Test` with `@Aspect` annotation will make your class an Aspect, means Spring's `ApplicationContext` or `BeanFactory` will now read and scan your class to find `advices`, `pointcuts`, `joinpoints`, you can define your extra `cross-cutting functinality` (functionality which you keep separate from your business logic) which you want to get executed for some event like before a method call, after a method call, after method throw an exception etc.

`AOP (Aspect-oriented programming)` is design pattern which spring follows to provide you cross-cutting functionality while `Spring Security` is a part of complete spring framework, which you can use to secure your application

Spring Security internally uses AOP and Filters to do its work.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is annotation-style syntax and can be used by both Spring AOP and pure AspectJ, the second one is native AspectJ syntax and only works in pure AspectJ, not in proxy-based Spring AOP. But pure AspectJ (compiled by AspectJ compiler) can also be incorporated into Spring projects as described in the Spring manual,  chapter [Using AspectJ with Spring applications](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj).

As for which approach is better suited for implementing security, this is kind of a philosophical question as long as you do not describe your use case in detail, but my general suggestion is: If you use the Spring framework anyway, also use its security mechanisms. If you only consider using Spring because you want to use Spring AOP, I would rather advise you to stay away from a big framework used for a single purpose only and use pure AspectJ in your POJO application for implementing security.